Mediation analysis - categorical predictor - how to set hypothetical reference?
I am running a mediation analysis on a categorical X (race/ethnicity), binary Y (disease status), and ordinal M (can be any integer 0 - 10).
I had originally calculated a percent mediated (coefficient of indirect effect/coefficient of total effect). However, a reviewer stated that since the coefficients are from linear and non-linear logistic models, they would not be on the same scale, and therefore percent mediated may be problematic. I do understand this point.
However, they then go on to say that percent mediated by division of coefficients may be biased by the difference in M between the X (race/ethnicity) subgroups. Example: X1 may have higher M than X2, and so X1 would have a bigger effect on the indirect estimate, leading to a higher percent mediated. They suggest "It would be better to set the same hypothetic M value for all subgroups to obtain comparable percent mediation estimates for all racial/ethnic subgroups."
It is this suggestion that I am having trouble understanding conceptually. What procedure are they suggesting I do? I have been using HAYES for R.

I was just wondering how you calculated mediated effect. Say you have 3 categories for some categorical X. Your mediation model is X --> M --> Y. For X you used dummies, yes? It is not so straightforward to calculate the mediated effect and total effect of X then. So, apart for the problem with the different scales, how did you do it, given that for both M and Y a linear regression would be suited?

@BenP Correct, I specified dummy coding of X using the mcx function of Hayes' PROCESS. For outcome M, linear regression was used. But for outcome Y, a logistic regression was used since it is a binary outcome. My result was a different total, direct, and indirect effect for g-1 categories of X compared to the same reference group of X.

That seems OK, I forgot you used process. Hayes shows such calculations in his book, although I'm not sure about the division to get a percentage indirect of the total. You could look that up and see if Hayes says something about bias.

@BenP Thanks for your insight! Any thoughts on what the reviewer is suggesting when they suggest to "set the same hypothetic M value"?

Calculating indirect effects in a causal chain model like X --> M --> Y in case the outcome variable Y is binary and logistic regression is used, is less straighforward than in case Y is continuous and modelled by linear regression. A relatively simple method is employed by the Hayes macro called "Process". The indirect effect is obtained there by multiplication of the regression effects in the path from X to Y via M, in the usual way, with the caveat that the effect of M on Y (controlled for X) is expressed on the loggodds scale. The so obtained indirect effect of X on Y via M expresses what happens with the logodds of Y if X increases 1 unit.
However as you can read e.g. in this working paper and in the book of Hayes that comes with the process macro "Introduction to Mediation, Moderation, and Conditional Process Analysis", third edition paragraaf 14.9, there are other visions and recent studies on how to express indirect or mediated effects for binary outcomes. These are more complicated than the simple method used in the Hayes process macro at this moment.
From the point of view of the method used by Process, I cannot see why what the reviewer suggests would be a meaningful idea. Given that you explained in your question exactly what the reviewer meant (which I cannot be completely certain of, of course) than following the reviewer's idea would lead to a "strange" result for the indirect effect. That is, keeping the mediator at a constant value actually neutralizes the first path in the chain. The mediator changes because X changes and this change in the mediator in turn causes a change in Y. Hence, keeping the mediator at a constant value does make no sense, imho. Also, I think that if the indirect effect that the process macro produces would be known to be biased and it would be simple to adjust for this bias, Hayes would have issued a warned against this bias or even would have given the adjusted effect the reviewer seems to suggest. However, that is only a feeling I have.
But I have to be a bit cautious here. It may be that the reviewer is better informed than I am and you are and knows about a bias present in the Hayes macro result and also knows the cure for it. Given the formulation of his suggestion (keeping the mediator at a constant value) that seems less likely to me.

Thank you for your answer! I do agree with you and your reasoning, and I do believe I accurately represented the reviewer's concern. I will do some more reading on this topic to respond to the reviewer's concern.
